# Code executes more times than expected

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make these small popup menus for each table cell, but `console.log("OK")` is being executed more times than actual 'click' events occur. What am I doing wrong here?

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><div class="popup"></div></td>
        <td><div class="popup"></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><div class="popup"></div></td>
        <td><div class="popup"></div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("td").live('click', function (e) {

        $(this).find(".popup").fadeIn("fast");

        $(".popup").on('click', function (e) {
            console.log("OK");
        });

        return false;

    });

    $("html").on('click', function (e) {
        $(".popup").fadeOut("fast");
    });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/V9XQm/

Comment: Provide relevant code in question! (Thx adeneo!)

Comment: You are nesting event declaration

Comment: Your popup click binding function is inside another click bound function, why is that so?

Comment: Binding an event handler inside an event handler, has to be a trillion duplicates.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for a code review.

Comment: @zzzzBov It's not asking for code review. He's got a bug. He is asking for help finding it. He even provided his code, and explained what symptom he's seeing. That's more than I've seen from some newbies.

Comment: @Lynn is right. The reason this is off-topic is that it will only help this individual. It is a debugging request. SO is for archivable programming questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to move your click handler for `.popup` div outside of the click handler of `td` elements:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("td").live('click', function (e) {
        $(this).find(".popup").fadeIn("fast");
        return false;
    });

    $(".popup").on('click', function (e) {
        console.log("OK");
    });

    $("html").on('click', function (e) {
        $(".popup").fadeOut("fast");
    });

});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V9XQm/1/)**

Also note that `.live()` was deprecated since version `1.7` and removed in version `1.9`. You should use **[.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on)** instead

Comment: Note: .live() has been deprecated. Stick with .on()

Comment: +1 Nice answer, and thanks for taking the time to help him. Voting to reopen this question.

Comment: Thanks, @Felix! That worked. But `.on()` doesn't work for my original code, because I have a dynamically created table. Should I just stick with `.live()` in that case?

Comment: @eudoxyz You can use [**event delegation**](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) for dynamically added elements by applying `.on()`